# Sort data in multiple array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have an array like this:

```
   $B = array(
    array("firstnam" =>"A", "lastname"=>"D", "grade" => "k1", "score" => 50),
    array("firstnam" =>"B", "lastname"=>"C", "grade" => "k4", "score" => 20),
    array("firstnam" =>"C", "lastname"=>"B", "grade" => "k3", "score" => 10),
    array("firstnam" =>"D", "lastname"=>"A", "grade" => "k2", "score" => 80)
);
```

Comment: The good algorithm to do what? I'm not following what the question is...

Comment: how do you represent your data? per row? can you post a bit more of your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to sort h1-3 by h4, try this:

```
array_multisort($h4, SORT_NUMERIC, SORT_ASC, $h3, SORT_NUMERIC, SORT_ASC, $h2, SORT_NUMERIC, SORT_ASC, $h1, SORT_NUMERIC, SORT_ASC);
```

If this isn't what you're looking for, try rephrasing your question.

Comment: yes,thanks I do not know about this build in function,nice.@Unsigned Code labs

Answer (score 0):

```
public function sortByHeader($columns, $sortOrder=1/* or -1 for desc */) {
    $this->sort_columns = $columns;
    $this->sort_order = $sortOrder;
    uasort($this->data, array($this, "cmp"));
}

public function cmp($a, $b) {
    foreach ($this->sort_columns as $column) {
        // It's also important to check datatypes if you have string and it in diff columns
        if ($a[$column] > $b[$column]) {
            return $this->sort_order;
        }
        if ($a[$column] < $b[$column]) {
            return -$this->sort_order;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

uasort allows to use custom callback for sorting your data. See PHP man for reference

Comment: why you need $columns as array?what the problems if you $columns = array("score") or array("score","lastname") ;

Comment: If you have same values for score, data will be sorted by lastname. I forgot to add directions for each sorting column, it will be more helpful. Also you cannot use > < signs for strings, strcmp should be used instead.